# In PHP, regular expression to remove the pound sign from a string, if exists

Tags: php, regex

In PHP, I want to remove the pound sign (#) from a hex string *if* it exists.

I tried the following:

```
$str = "#F16AD3";

//Match the pound sign in the beginning
if (preg_match("/^\#/", $str)) {
  //If it's there, remove it
  preg_replace('/^\#/', '', $str);
};

print $str;
```

But it didn't work.  It prints out `#F16AD3`

How can I remove the pound only if it exists?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
echo ltrim('#F16AD3', '#');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php

EDIT: If you are only testing for the pound sign at the beginning of the string you can can use [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

```
if(strpos('#F16AD3', '#') === 0) {
    // found it
}
```

Comment: I failed to even mention a better alternative, which this is. +1

Comment: Strange, I am trying to +1 you, and it goes to -1 when I do???  Ah, it is because some dolt down voted you.

Comment: Thats a very simple and effective way to do it but doesn't check if the pound sign is there or not

Comment: @Mark: It does nothing if there is no `#`, so it's fine to call it without any check.

Answer (score 6):

You have to assign the response back to the variable:

```
$str = preg_replace('/^\#/', '', $str);
```

Also, you don't need to do the check with preg_match at all, it's redundant.

Answer (score 4):

If you're just looking for a pound sign at the beginning of a string, why not use something simpler than regular expressions?

```
if ($str[0] == '#')
  $str = substr($str, 1);
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason you are not seeing a change is because you are discarding the result of `preg_replace`. You need to assign it back to the variable:

```
//Match the pound sign in the beginning
if (preg_match("/^#/", $str)){
    //If it's there, remove it
    $str = preg_replace('/^#/', '', $str);
};
```

However, notice that the call to `preg_match` is completely redundant. You are already checking if it exists in `preg_replace`! :) Therefore, just do this:

```
//If there is a pound sign at the beginning, remove it
$str = preg_replace('/^#/', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

@ennuikiller is correct, no escaping necessary.  Also, you don't need to check for a match, just replace it:

```
<?php
$color = "#ff0000";

$color = preg_replace("/^#/", "", $color);
echo $color;

?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
ff0000
```

Answer (score 1):

Why using preg_replace for this?

```
echo str_replace("#","",$color);
```

Comment: He may have been doing this to ensure that it was at the start of the string.

Comment: Correct it is invalid if its at the end

Answer (score 0):

You're calling two different preg functions, this might be over-optimization, but `str_replace('#' , ''  , $color)` solves your problem faster/efficiently.  I'm sure other people will answer your specific regex issue.