# How to match a pound (#) symbol in a regex in php (for hashtags)

Tags: php, regex

Very simple, I need to match the `#` symbol using a regex. I'm working on a hashtag detector.

I've tried searching in google and in stack overflow. One related post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536101/regular-expression-to-remove-the-pound-sign-from-a-string-if-exists), but since he wanted to remove the # symbol from the string he didn't use regex.

I've tried the regexes `/\b\#\w\w+/`, and `/\b#\w\w+/` and they don't work and if I remove the `#`, it detects the word.

Comment: Did you try to escape it? `'\#'`

Comment: please post sample text you want to match from. your problem is not likely to be the # symbol, but rather the regex you're embedding it within.

Comment: @Vague: it looks like he did, in the first regex he posted.

Comment: @DavidThomas He edited the post! I'm sure of it! :)

Comment: You probably mistake what `\b` means.

Comment: Why do you want to use a regex at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to escape it (it's probably the `\b` that's throwing it off):

```
if (preg_match('/^\w+#(\w+)/', 'abc#def', $matches)) {
    print_r($matches);
}

/* output of $matches:
Array
(
    [0] => abc#def
    [1] => def
)
*/
```

Comment: I want it to detect #abcdef, not asdasd#this.

Comment: But you answered what I asked.

Answer (score 13):

`#` does not have any special meaning in a regex, unless you use it as the delimiter. So just put it straight in and it should work.

Note that `\b` detects a word boundary, and in `#abc`, the word boundary is after the `#` and before the `abc`. Therefore, <del>you need to use</del> the `\b` is superfluous and you just need `#\w\w+`.

Comment: Why do you need `\w` twice?  Doesn't `\w+` mean one or more?

Comment: Because it was that way in the OP. Ideally I'd use `\w{2,}` to mean "two or more".

Comment: The `\b` in `#\b\w` is obviously superfluous.

Comment: I needed he word to start with #,but you are right, I misunderstood what \b means

Answer (score 4):

With the comment on the earlier answer, you want to avoid matching `x#x`.
In that case, your don't need `\b` but `\B`:

`\B#(\w\w+)`

(if you really need two-or-more word characters after the #).

The `\B` means NON-word-boundary, and since `#` is not a word character, this matches exactly if the previous character is not a word character.

Comment: A little late, but +1 anyway, because nobody else pointed this out.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following regex: `/\#(\w+)/` to match a hashtag with just the hashtag word, or: `/\#\w+/` will match the entire hashtag including the hash.

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth I only managed to match a hash(#) character as a string.  In awk the parser takes out the comments as first thing.  The only syntax that can 'hold' a # is

```
"#"
```

So in my case I took-out lines with only comments as:

```
$1 == "#" { next; }
```

I also attempted to make the hash a regex:

```
HASH_PATTERN = "^#"

$1 ~ HASH_PATTERN { next; }
```

... This *also* works.  So I'm thinking you an put the whole expression in a string like: HASH_PATTERN.

The string equals does work quite well.  It isn't a perfect solution, just a starter.