# How to match a pound (#) symbol at the beginning of a word using regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex, hashtag

I need a regex to match a word that starts with #.

I wrote this question [How to match a pound (#) symbol in a regex in php (for hashtags)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421948/how-to-match-a-pound-symbol-in-a-regex-in-php-for-hashtags), but I forgot to explain that I need the # at the beginning of a word.

I need to match **#word**,  **#123**,  **#12_sdas**, but not **1#234** or **#1234**.

For example, in `"#match1 notMatch not#Match #match2 notMatch #match3"`, only **#match1**, **#match2** and **#match3** should appear.

Edit: I just want one pound (#), followed by one or more [a-ZA-Z0-9_]. The match can't have any of [a-ZA-Z0-9_] before.

My problem was finding the pound at the beginning of the word.

Comment: see the list of related posts on the right.

Comment: I think you need to give a clearer explanation what exactly should be matched. It's not clear in which cases numbers are allowed. (e.g. why match #123 but not #1234)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_match_all('/(?:^|\s+)(#\w+)/', $your_input, $your_results);
// print results
print_r($your_results);
```

It will match all words beginning with a `#` symbol. Words can be sepearted by all valid whitespace characters (so one of `\t\r\n\v\f`)

**Example**

```
//input
#match1 notMatch not#Match #match2 notMatch #match3
//output
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => #match1
            [1] =>  #match2
            [2] =>  #match3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => #match1
            [1] => #match2
            [2] => #match3
        )

)
```

Comment: The `^` at the start of your regex requires space and will only work on tags at the start .. I think you want `/(?:^|\s+)#(\w+)/'`

Comment: Not working. Its not detecting nothing

Comment: fixed the regex to match at line beginnings. And added sample output.

Comment: php 8.1 - not working properly

subject 'asdas ###ewewe #767 # tata #  zbiuta'

result is array repeted twice with result

#767

Answer (score 4):

```
preg_match_all('/(?:^|\s)(#\w+)/', $string, $results);
```

EDIT: don't have a php cli to test this, but the regex works in python at the very least.

Comment: this does not need the hashsymbol to be at the very beginning of a word...

Comment: Does now! Sorry, missed that requirement.

Comment: +1 before i realized it should not match #1234

Comment: I have no idea why it should match #123 but not #1234...

Comment: +1 this, accepted the one over this. It can match #1234 if it comes after a non \w char. The regex is fine, but the one over separates the hashtag with the # and without it ($match returns #tag and tag in positions 0 and 1 respectively).